# Limiting custom annotation for Spring application

Tags: spring

I want to create a custom spring annotation which will work under some conditions or parameters. But as a business constraint I need to share the library which has Genre annotation to all my applications. Is it possible to configure my annotation for limiting to some of my applications like @Profile annotation?

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER}) @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface Genre {
  String value();
}
```

and its usage

```
public class MovieRecommender {
@Autowired

   @Genre("Action")
   private MovieCatalog actionCatalog; 

   private MovieCatalog comedyCatalog;

   @Autowired
   public void setComedyCatalog(@Genre("Comedy") MovieCatalog comedyCatalog) { 
      this.comedyCatalog = comedyCatalog;
   }
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to alter the behaviour of `@Autowired` annotation.

However you can easily implement your own `BeanPostProcessor` and use all the convenience Spring classes, such as `AnnotationUtils`, `ReflectionUtils`, etc.

On one project we needed custom JAX-WS port injection. So we created `@InjectedPort` annotation and implemented our own `InjectedPortAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` (this just illustrates the simplicity of custom injection logic, the purpose of the code itself is unrelated to the question):

```
@Override
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean,  String beanName) {
    // Walk through class fields and check InjectedPort annotation presence
    ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(bean.getClass(), new FieldCallback() {
        @Override
        public void doWith(final Field field) {
            // Find InjectedPort annotation
            final InjectedPort injectedPort = field.getAnnotation(InjectedPort.class);
            if (injectedPort == null) {
                return; // Annotation is not present
            }
            // Get web service class from the annotation parameter
            Class<?> serviceClass = injectedPort.value();
            // Find web service annotation on the specified class
            WebServiceClient serviceAnnotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(serviceClass, WebServiceClient.class);
            if (serviceAnnotation == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Missing WebService " + "annotation on '" + serviceClass + "'.");
            }
            // Get web service instance from the bean factory
            Service service = (Service) beanFactory.getBean(serviceClass);
            // Determine the name of the JAX-WS port
            QName portName = new QName(service.getServiceName().getNamespaceURI(), findPortLocalName(serviceClass, field.getType()));
            // Obtain the JAX-WS port
            Object port = service.getPort(portName, field.getType());
            // Inject the port into the target bean
            ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
            ReflectionUtils.setField(field, bean, port);
        }
    });
    return bean;
}
```